# Embed whole website into UIWebView (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I've got a simple question (at least that's what I thought in the beginning):
Is it possible to simply load a website with HTML, CSS and Javascript into a UIWebView without having to adjust anything?
I've got the problem that I'm trying to achieve this with a particular website, but the Javascript code won't execute as it should.

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT: Here you can see the website: `http://176.28.43.237:8088/`

When I try to load it local in UIWebView nothing happens, when I open the website in browser it works as expected. Its 100% the same code.

Comment: which web site ? can you share the link. Any particular javascript function that is not working ? did u check the same site in Mobile Safari browser ?

Comment: Can you add the related code ?

Comment: The problem was that I tried to load the JavaScript stuff from the Bundle, but when you add the JavaScript-Files, Xcode will add them to the target (Compile Sources) and not copy them (Copy Bundle Sources). And because there is no compiler rule for JS-Files, they will be ignored. So you have to remove them from the build target and add them manually to the bundle sources.